# flutter : How to split video file into chunks or in multiple parts, to upload it to server

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video-processing

I am working on a flutter project where, I want to split the video file into multiple parts and upload file to server, in flutter is it possible to split the file into multiple parts?

`I did not found any plugin or library to split the file into multiple chunks.`

Comment: why to split? cannot you upload the whole file? with splitting how would the server know how many chunks do you have? in file name or something?

Comment: because we have server that is not accepting file, size more than 20mb, thats why i am trying to split the file into multiple parts (array) and upload one by one with index of splited item

Comment: check [ChunkedStreamReader](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html) then